# Count from 1 to 10 and repeat inside a button link dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to write a script that counts from 1 to 10 and after 10 it will repeat, Inside a buttom link.

Example:

Submit

First click goes to "url/page1.html"

Second click to "url/page2.html"

Third to "url/page3.html"

Fourth to "url/page4.html"

And up to ten click "url/page10.html"

After the hit number 10, it must run repeat to 1 agin.

Example2:

First click goes to "url/page1.html", click 2 = "url/page2.html", click 3 = "url/page3.html", click 4 = "url/page4.html, click 5 = "url/page5.html, click 5 = "url/page5.html, click 6 = "url/page6.html, click 7 = "url/page7.html, click 8 = "url/page8.html, click 9 = "url/page9.html click 10 = "url/page10.html and now repeat click 11 = "url/page1.html, click 12 = "url/page2.html, click 13 = "url/page3.html, click 14 = "url/page4.html

Right now im using this script but its don't repeat the counter. 
I want to send users to different links so whatever the ip user comes from should it count correctly ip 1 goes to page1.html when next visitor comes to my site and click on the button the will go to page2.html nxt to page3.html

Code right now:

```
 <button onclick="myScript(10)">Submit</button>

 <script>

 let currentPage = 1;

  function myScript(totalPages) {
  if (currentPage === totalPages) {
    return window.location.href=`/page10.html`
  }
   currentPage = currentPage < totalPages ? currentPage + 1 : 1;
   return window.location.href=`/page${currentPage}.html`;
  }

  </script>
```

Hope someone can give me a good example of how this should run, prefer php or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<button onclick="myScript(10)">Submit</button>

<script>
 //get current url
 let url = new URL(window.location.href);

 //get currentPage
 let currentPage = parseInt(url.searchParams.get("currentPage")) || 0;

 function myScript(totalPages) {

   currentPage = currentPage < totalPages ? currentPage + 1 : 1;

   return window.location.href=`/page${currentPage}.html?currentPage=${currentPage}`;
 }

</script>
```

By starting at 0 you can get rid of the first if statement. When the user hits the button the 11th time currentPage (10) is not less then totalPages (10), so your code will reset currentPage to 1.

Comment: But will not start from 1 every time a new user comes to my page? I need a script that remembers what side of the last visitor came into and take the next page.

Comment: I updated my answer. The update attempts to store the currentPage as a get param, which should make the code aware of the current page the user is on.

Comment: Nothing happens on my side http://www.nltrading.dk/routingscript/page.html

Comment: Updated post: I had the wrong null coalescing operator. It should do something now.

Comment: It works now, but when i come from a new ip it starts from scratch it must go on

Comment: That's beyond what JavaScript can do alone. You would need a web server to track the number of request received and to route the based on which page is next in line.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change your code into something like this:

```
<button onclick="myScript(10)">Submit</button>

<script>

let currentPage = 1;

function myScript(totalPages) {
    var location = '';
    if (currentPage % totalPages == 0) {
        location = '\/page10.html';
    }else{
        location = '\/page'+currentPage % totalPages+'.html';
    }
    currentPage++;
    return window.location.href = location;
}
</script>
```

Comment: But will not start from 1 every time a new user comes to my page? I need a script that remembers what side of the last visitor came into and take the next page.

Comment: I think that you should use the cookie or something like that to store the last page visited. 
Javascript can't do that thing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<button onclick="myScript()">submit</button>
var i=1;
function myScript(){
   i+=1;
   if (i==1){
     window.location.href=`/page${i}.html`;
     i++;
     return;
   }
   if (i==10){
     i=1; 
   }
   window.location.href=`/page${i}.html`
}
```

Comment: But will not start from 1 every time a new user comes to my page? I need a script that remembers what side of the last visitor came into and take the next page.

Comment: Yes, it works fine if you press 4 times from my computer it goes right, but if I try to hit fiveth time on my mobile it starts from 1 again. It does not have to continue as there were 5 clicks on the same device. hope you understand:)

Comment: You should try to save the variable 'i' somewhere, maybe in a php, Sorry but i don't know this ahah